# In C# I get a System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException only for specific file path

Tags: c#, file, directory

I have the following code in C#:

```
FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePathAndName);
file.Directory.Create();
File.WriteAllText(filePathAndName, headers + singleOption.Value);
```

When the file name is

> `D:\Option Data\DiscountOptionData\Single Option Files\NUL\NUL2008-09-20p32.50.csv`

then it throws a System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException. In fact, any with `NUL` in them throw the exception.

But any other file names I'm using, such as

> `D:\Option Data\DiscountOptionData\Single Option Files\NSI\NSI2006-06-17c50.002006-02-09.csv`

do not throw exceptions.

The relevant parts of the filename are read from an excel file.  I've tried using `LEN([Cell])` on them and can't find any hidden characters.

Comment: [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions).

Comment: `NUL` is not a valid name for a file or directory - see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

Comment: Try to simply create a folder called `NUL` on your system. It wont work. You could check if the path contains \NUL\ and then rename it to something more suitable, like `-NUL-` or something similar.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, thank you, I'll have to rethink how I organise things.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use `nul` (or `con` or `prn`) for file names, since these are considered special devices by windows. You can see this if you open up a `cmd` window and enter `type nul`:

```
c:\pax> type nul
c:\pax> type nulx
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

---

In fact, it even misbehaves with an extension. I once had a source file `const.h` which I renamed to `con.h` and then spent a bit of time wondering why my code wasn't compiling. Turns out, because I'd used `#include "con.h"`,  Windows had
helpfully opened up the console device to read my header file.

In other words, it was waiting for me to type it in :-)

---

If you *must* have a directory hierarchy where `NUL*.csv` files are stored, one solution is to use a prefix to ensure special device names don't appear, something like:

```
D:\OptnData\DscntOptnData\SnglOptnFls\dirNUL\NUL2008-09-20p32.50.csv
                                      ^^^^^^
                                     This bit
```

Comment: I suspected that maybe NUL meant something, but couldn't find anything on it in C#.  So is there a solution?  NUL is the name of a stock, and the other part is an option code, so I kind of want to keep it the same.  But I guess I could replace it with NUX or something, but the workaround would need to be included anywhere I use the files.

Comment: @YesThisIsMe, see the bottom of the answer. You can leave the code as `NUL`, you just have to ensure you don't use that on its *own* in a directory component. It's easily fixed by adding a constant prefix like `dir`.

Comment: Now just the decision whether to throw away and replace the million odd files my computer has written over the past couple of days, which have pretty much stopped me being able to do anything else on it :)  But I've got some 128Gb USB's coming in the mail to help speed it up anyway so might be better to start from scratch.